# Decidability and Subformula Property

Tags: logic, proof-theory

How does one prove the decidability of intuitionistic propositional logic, given the subformula property if a formula $A \rightarrow B$ is a subformula of itself?

Two of the texts I'm reading say that this proof is immediate, but what prevents one from repeatedly applying a rule like:

$\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B \\
----- \\
\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$

Is it that decidability is not actually immediate from the subformula property alone and these authors are implicitly appealing to the specific rules of the logic in question, or am I missing something?

In other words, does decidability only follow from a slightly stronger property like the proper subformula property, or some other strictly decreasing order on sequents?

I am looking specifically at Girard's [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf), in which he says decidability is an "immediate corollary" of the weak normalization theorem on page 24.

Comment: I don't believe decidability follows immediately from the subformula property in the standard Gentzen-style sequent calculus presentation of intuitionistic propositional logic. But the difficulties arise from the rule of contraction rather than your identity rule, which is not one of the standard rules (and is completely pointless). However, it's not really possible to say more about this if you don't tell us what texts you are reading or give more details about what those texts say.

Comment: Check Troelstra and Schwichtenberg's Basic Proof Theory book. In the second edition the proof is in page 108-109, and there is a small explanation regarding a repetition of a sequent. The gist of it is that unless the sequent itself is an axiom a different path is needed to prove it (so we can ignore repetitions).

Comment: @RobArthan My identity rule was intended to be a counterexample to the immediate proof of decidability, given the subformula property.  I guess my issue is that I do not see the immediacy of the proof. It seems like you would have to prove that, roughly, the size of the sequent is getting smaller at each step in the proof, which is not immediate from the subformula property because $A \rightarrow B$ is a subformula of itself.  Is that true?  Perhaps the link I supplied will help.

Answer (score -1):

Proofs in sequent calculi can be represented as directed acyclic graphs instead of lists. In this case, there are no repetitions, and so there is a finite number of proofs that contain only subformulas of the derived sequent. Decidability follows from this finite search space.